# How to write to a different file everyday day of the week using bash

Tags: bash, file, shell, output

I have a script that pulls information from a file and outputs it to a different file. What i need to do is run this script everyday but output to a different file. I will have this in the crontab to run everyday at the same time but i dont know how to output to a different file everyday. Is there a loop i can use?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop. Rather, use a [stdout/stderr redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) to a filename created using 'date'

e.g.

```
$ myprocess.sh > `date +"%m-%d-%Y"`.log
```

so date is executed in the backticks (this is known as [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html)) and the output substituted in the line. Here the [formatted output of date](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/) is used as the log file name (in this case 04-24-2014.log)